# Install Offline Windows Updates(.msu) to remote servers

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update

I'm trying to get a script together to remotely install some windows updates on some remote servers that are connected in an offline domain.

I have tried regular PS Remoting and after some research, I think what I am trying to do isnt supported by microsoft. When checking my event logs I have a bunch of these errors.

**Edit**

I wanted to add that I have tried running the `.\Install2012R2.ps1` script from my local computer, modified to have the `Invoke-Command` in that and have it run the update portion of the original `Install2012R2.ps1` and I would get the same errors.

I was hoping that by placing the script on each server that it would like that more.

**End Edit**

```
Windows update  could not be installed because of error 2147942405 "Access is denied."
(Command line: ""C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe" "C:\Updates\windows8.1-kb4556853-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart")
```

I have tried running `Invoke-Command` as credentialed to an administrator account on the servers but I have been having no luck and was looking for some advice if someone has maybe tried/done this before.

```
$Servers = @("V101-Test1","V101-Test2")
$Username = 'admin'
$Password = 'Password'#not actual password
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
New-PSSession -ComputerName $Servers

foreach($Server in $Servers){
    Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Source\Temp -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "\\$Server\c$\Updates\" -Force
}

Invoke-Command $Servers -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock{

& "C:\Updates\Install2012R2.ps1"

}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is the actual install code of the Install2012R2.ps1 script

```
$updatedir= "./"
$files = Get-ChildItem $updatedir -Recurse


$msus = $files | ? {$_.extension -eq ".msu"}
$exes = $files | ? {$_.extension -eq ".exe"}

foreach ($file in $msus){
    $KBCtr++
    $fullname = $file.fullname
        
    # Need to wrap in quotes as folder path may contain space   
    $fullname = "`"" + $fullname + "`""
    $KBN = $fullname.split('-')[1]

# Need to wrap in quotes as folder path may contain space   
$fullname = "`"" + $fullname + "`""
    # Specify the command line parameters for wusa.exe
        $parameters = $fullname + " /quiet /norestart"

        # Start services and pass in the parameters
    $install = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "wusa",$parameters )
    $install.WaitForExit()
}
```

Comment: Does `Install2012R2.ps1` connect to any remote servers for anything? This would include a something over a UNC path like `\\server.domain.tld\ShareName$\somefile.ext`.

Comment: No it doesn't, all it does is collect all the .msus and attempts to install them.
 **EDIT** I added the actual install information of the ``Install2012R2.ps1`` to the original post at the end

Comment: Where does it collect the MSUs from? I don't see that you're copying them before running invoke command, so I assume it needs to pull them from somewhere? Or are they already staged on the target server under `C:\Updates`?

Comment: Where is `$updatedDir` getting it's value from? *What* is the value of `$updatedDir`?

Comment: It copies the files from my local machine in ``C:\Source\Temp`` and places them on each server in ``C:\Updates``. It does it in the only ``foreach`` loop in my launch script

Comment: Ah, I see. My mistake.

Comment: I added the ``$UpdatedDir`` variable into the second half. the ``Install2012R2.ps1`` script resides on the server with the MSU files in ``C:\Updates``

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why `wusa.exe` is failing here with Access Denied, but here is a PowerShell-native approach you can try. If nothing else, it should give you a clearer indication via the captured error information as to what the underlying issue is:

```
Add-WindowsPackage -Path C:\Updates\OurHeroicUpdate.msu -Online -PreventPending -NoRestart
```

- `-Path` is the path to the `msu` file
- `-Online` tells `Add-WindowsPackage` to modify the currently "mounted image" (the running version) of Windows (as opposed to an offline disk image you could also apply it to)
- `-PreventPending` prevents installing the `msu` if there is already a pending change, like needing to reboot for updates.

[`Add-WindowsPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/add-windowspackage?view=windowsserver2019-ps) is part of the [`DISM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) module available under Windows PowerShell, and is the functional equivalent of `dism /packagepath:"cabfile"`, although it can take an `msu` where `dism.exe` only allows a `cab`.